# How to pause or continue Foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

This is my code,

```
        <?php $i=1; foreach($xls as $xls): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $xls->jenis; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $xls->user; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $xls->nama; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $xls->unit; ?></td>
            <?php if (is_array($jawab) || is_object($jawab)){ ?>
        <?php if(isset($jawab)) {?>
        <?php $limit=0;?>
        <?php foreach($jawab as $row): ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['ket_jawaban']; ?></td>
        <?php $limit++;  if($limit==2) break;  endforeach; }} ?>    

        </tr>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>  
</tbody>
```

How do I  make `each` print 2 lines from `foreach` 2nd move to the bottom line (`tr`)

OK, with explanation:

The above code prints like this:
[image: the above code prints like this]

But I want to print like this:
[image: But I want to print like this]

Comment: Why all the PHP opening and closing tags? It's making your code quite hard to read..

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain better.

Comment: ok sir,question updated

Comment: i'am sory with my code if quite hard to read, 
I plan to fix it if the code is running well

Comment: A [Minimum Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should Not include messy or unnecessary code.  You should go out of your way to make it easy for us to help you.  That includes easy to read and use code.  There are thousands of other questions we could look at instead of this one.  And none here is obligated. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also cleaner code can uncover hidden bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Change the name of one of your $jawab variables in the foreach loop.

```
<?php foreach($jawab as $jawab): ?>
```

And NEVER repeat a variable name in a loop.

UPDATE:

Try to change your loop:

```
<?php $limit=0;?>
<?php foreach($jawab as $row): ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['ket_jawaban']; ?></td>
<?php $limit++;  if($limit==2) break;  endforeach; }} ?>
```

to:

```
<td><?php echo $jawab[i*2]['ket_jawaban']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $jawab[i*2-1]['ket_jawaban']; ?></td>
```

Comment: It's print all data each row... i hope each 2 row printed move to bottom line

Comment: did you change the repeated $xls too?

Comment: i change $xls to $Newxls but it's same

Comment: Answer updated. A little dirt but I hope it could do the job.